# Blessing the Children on Friday Night

Tags: minhag, blessing, sources-mekorot, children-parenting, leil-shabbat

I have noticed that many families (including my own) have the custom for the father to bless all the children on Friday night before kiddush.

When and where did this custom originate, and by whom, and why is it done before Kiddush on Friday night?

Comment: I have seen families where both the father and the mother bless, too.

Answer (score 9):

The Minhag Yisroel Torah 271:2 brings in the name of the Maavar Yabok and the Sefer HaChaim from the brother of the Maharal M'Prag that we bless the children Friday night since on Shabbos there is no Satan that is Mekatreg and also the Tzinorei (pipes of) Brachos are open then.

Rabbi Yaakov Emden in his Siddur writes that it is a Minhag Yisroel to bless the children Friday night placing both hands on the child. In the Vilna Gaon's Siddur it also mentions the Minhag of giving a Bracha, however there it says you should only place the right hand on the child.

[Why Does Hashem Bless Us Like Efraim And Menashe?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4806/why-does-hashem-bless-us-like-efraim-and-menashe)

Comment: The _Tora T'mima_ (in _Naso_) wonders "what people depend on in blessing someone while putting hands on his head, as people do for blessing bridegrooms and the like, inasmuch as, as we've seen [above in the TT], such a way of blessing is restricted to _kohanim_ only, and for others there's an _isur ase_. It's a stretch to say that what's granted to _kohanim_ is only [blessing with hands] with the wording of the benediction in the _p'sukim_ here, as, per _M'nachos_ 11:1, lifting the hands [alone] is considered an [avoda] like any other in the _bes hamikdash_. [continued]

Comment: [continued] "Now, I've heard from a trustworthy source that the _Vilna Gaon_ blessed Rabbi [someone] _Landa_, _posek_ of _Vilna_, at the time of his nuptials, and rested one hand on his head at the time. When asked about this, he explained that we don't find blessing with two hands except by the _kohanim_ in the _bes hamikdash_. But aside from that" no one had mentioned it.

Comment: @msh210, @Gershon Gold, A Rashi in parashas Pinchas notes that although Hashem commanded Moshe to lean his hand on Yehoshua (27:18), Moshe leaned both hands (27:23) and implies ayin yafa.  Although this is not a blessing (so the story is not in question, there is precedent for 2 hands being more generous.

Comment: Later question on this: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27274