# Should a parent bless a child resting one hand or both?

Tags: number, blessing, children-parenting, hands-fingers

When a parent gives the traditional blessing usually done on Shabbat evening should the parent place one hand on the head of the child or two?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7722/blessing-the-children-on-friday-night/7727#7727

Comment: @GershonGold: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1569/answered-elsewhere

Comment: @JNF: I did not say it was a duplicate, nor did I request that it be closed.

Comment: @GershonGold, I wasn't saying you did wrong :) only that this is the case.