# Halachic status of ישמך אלקים כאפרים וכמנשה

Tags: blessing, halacha-theory, avot-patriarch-fathers, children-parenting, vayechi

Yaakov blessed Ephraim and Menashe by stating that future generations would bless their children by saying "ישמך אלקים כאפרים וכמנשה" - "God make you like Ephraim and Manasseh" ([Gen. 48:20](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.48.20?lang=bi&aliyot=0)). Was this statement a prophecy or a proclamation?

There are various customs to bless children with these words at various times, on Friday night (according to [Wikipedia](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D) this is a fairly recent custom first recorded by R' Chaim the Maharal's brother) or at a bris (not in Artscroll Ashkenaz but I see it in various sources, particularly Encyclopedia Talmudit).  Rashi says it was used, but not at any particular time.

What's the halachic status of Yaakov's statement?  It's not counted as a mitzvah by the Rambam or as far as I know by anyone else.  It's apparently not even a "derabbanan"*, as it wasn't always practiced.  Was it a prophecy that "at some point various Jewish communities will have customs to use this form of blessing for their kids"?  Or was it a "derabbanan"* commandment that if you bless your kids, you should use these words?  Or that if you decide to give this blessing, you should say Ephraim first?  Or something else?

---

* putting derabbanan in quotes because I'm not sure the terminology makes sense before Matan Torah, but I imagine a command from Yaakov Avinu is at least as binding as a gezeirah by the amoraim.

Comment: I think it's a blessing to them that they should merit to have people want to bless after them. Consider וְלֻקַּ֤ח מֵהֶם֙ קְלָלָ֔ה לְכֹל֙ גָּל֣וּת יְהוּדָ֔ה אֲשֶׁ֥ר בְּבָבֶ֖ל לֵאמֹ֑ר יְשִֽׂמְךָ֤ יְהוָה֙ כְּצִדְקִיָּ֣הוּ וּכְאֶחָ֔ב אֲשֶׁר־קָלָ֥ם מֶֽלֶךְ־בָּבֶ֖ל בָּאֵֽשׁ׃ It's like the opposite of telling Achav that his bones will be eaten by dogs

Comment: I always wondered about this one myself. "God make you like Ephraim and Manasseh"    ?????   Later on, Ephraim and Menasseh were a large part of the Kingdom of Israel, breaking away/revolting, according to haShem's will, (from Ahijah the Shilonite's actions) from David/Judah and having a definitely more idolatry-based kingdom than Judah(most if not all of the time).

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/66582/is-the-traditional-blessing-of-the-children-allowed

Comment: Is there any way Yisrael in that verse could mean Yaakov the person as in earlier vayikrivu yemei yisrael lamut? Maybe it's Yosef talking in response to Yaakovs earlier comment?

Answer (score -3):

This blessing is based upon a general principle found in Torah that, *the acts of the Patriarchs are a sign for their descendants.* (מעשה אבות סימן לבנים) This principle is also applied in matters of halacha, like is found for example in the commentary [Divrei Yirmiyahu to Mishnah Torah, Hilchot Megillat Esther v'Chanukah, Chapter 1:3:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Divrei_Yirmiyahu_on_Mishneh_Torah%2C_Scroll_of_Esther_and_Hanukkah.1.3.1?vhe=Friedberg_Edition&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) by [Rabbi Yirmiyahu ben Benyamin Wolf](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37168&st=&pgnum=1) [(1811-1874](https://www.geni.com/people/%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95-%D7%9C%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%95-%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%93%D7%99%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99-%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95/6000000000008744439)), which says:

> ומעשה אבות סימן לבנים שאמרו רז"ל נתקיים בהנעשה אז לאבותינו גם לבניהם אחריהם עד כהיום הזה:

This is discussed in general at this [Wikipedia link](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9F_%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D) which points to the commentary of [Ramban to Bereshit 12:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.12.6?lang=bi&with=Ramban&lang2=he) which says:

> ויעבר אברם בארץ עד מקום שכם **אומר לך כלל תבין אותו בכל הפרשיות הבאות בענין אברהם יצחק ויעקב והוא ענין גדול הזכירוהו רבותינו בדרך קצרה ואמרו (תנחומא ט) כל מה שאירע לאבות סימן לבנים** ולכן יאריכו הכתובים בספור המסעות וחפירת הבארות ושאר המקרים ויחשוב החושב בהם כאלו הם דברים מיותרים אין בהם תועלת **וכולם באים ללמד על העתיד** **כי כאשר יבוא המקרה לנביא משלשת האבות יתבונן ממנו הדבר הנגזר לבא לזרעו ודע כי כל גזירת עירין כאשר תצא מכח גזירה אל פועל דמיון תהיה הגזרה מתקיימת על כל פנים** ולכן יעשו הנביאים מעשה בנבואות כמאמר ירמיהו שצוה לברוך והיה ככלותך לקרוא את דברי הספר הזה תקשור עליו אבן והשלכתו אל תוך פרת ואמרת ככה תשקע בבל וגו' (ירמיה נא סג סד) וכן ענין אלישע בהניחו זרועו על הקשת (מלכים ב יג טז-יז) ויאמר אלישע ירה ויור ויאמר חץ תשועה לה' וחץ תשועה בארם ונאמר שם (פסוק יט) ויקצוף עליו איש האלהים ויאמר להכות חמש או שש פעמים אז הכית את ארם עד כלה ועתה שלש פעמים תכה את ארם **ולפיכך החזיק הקב"ה את אברהם בארץ ועשה לו דמיונות בכל העתיד להעשות בזרעו והבן זה ואני מתחיל לפרש הענינים בפרט בפסוקים בעזרת השם** "ויעבור אברם בארץ עד מקום שכם" - היא עיר שכם כן זה שם המקום ההוא ושכם בן חמור על שם עירו נקרא וכתב רש"י נכנס לתוכה עד מקום שכם להתפלל על בני יעקב כשיבואו מן השדה עצבים ונכון הוא ואני מוסיף כי החזיק אברהם במקום ההוא תחלה וקודם שנתן לו את הארץ נרמז לו מזה כי בניו יכבשו המקום ההוא תחלה קודם היותם זוכים בו וקודם היות עון יושב הארץ שלם להגלותם משם ולכן אמר והכנעני אז בארץ וכאשר נתן לו הקב"ה הארץ במאמר אז נסע משם ונטע אהל בין בית אל ובין העי כי הוא המקום אשר כבש יהושע בתחלה ויתכן שהזכיר הכתוב והכנעני אז בארץ להורות על ענין הפרשה לומר כי אברם בא בארץ כנען ולא הראהו השם הארץ אשר יעדו ועבר עד מקום שכם והכנעני הגוי המר והנמהר אז בארץ ואברם ירא ממנו ולכן לא בנה מזבח לה' ובבואו במקום שכם באלון מורה נראה אליו השם ונתן לו הארץ וסרה יראתו כי כבר הובטח בארץ אשר אראך ואז בנה מזבח לה' לעבדו בפרהסיא "ואלון מורה" - זהו במקום שכם ונקרא גם כן "אלוני מורה" כמו שכתוב (דברים יא ל) מול הגלגל אצל אלוני מורה ושם הר גריזים והר עבל בשכם וקרוב לירדן שבאו שם בתחילת ביאתם בארץ אבל "אלוני ממרא" הוא מקום אשר הוא בארץ חברון רחוק מן הירדן ודע כי בכל מקום שיאמר הכתוב "אלוני ממרא" שם "ממרא" הוא על איש אמורי שהמקום ההוא שלו כמו שנאמר (להלן יד יג) והוא שוכן באלוני ממרא האמורי אחי אשכול ואחי ענר וכל "אלון מורה" ו"אלוני מורה" נקרא המקום ההוא על שם איש ששמו "מורה" אבל זה כנעני הוא מארץ הכנעני היושב בערבה וכשיזכיר הכתוב ממרא סתם הוא שם העיר כמו שנאמר (להלן לה כז) ויבא יעקב אל יצחק אביו ממרא קרית הארבע היא חברון על פני ממרא היא חברון (להלן כג יט) כי האיש אשר לו אלוני נקרא על שם העיר וכן שכם בן חמור כשם העיר שכם ובבראשית רבה (מב ח) על דעתיה דרבי יהודה אתרא הוא דשמיה ממרא ועל דעתיה דרבי נחמיה גברא הוא דשמיה ממרא

The principle is illustrated with Avraham, the first of the Avot, in Bereshit Rabbah 48:7 which says:

> רַבִּי בֶּרֶכְיָה מִשּׁוּם רַבִּי לֵוִי אָמַר יָשַׁב כְּתִיב, בִּקֵּשׁ לַעֲמֹד, **אָמַר לוֹ הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא** שֵׁב, **אַתָּה סִימָן לְבָנֶיךָ**, מָה אַתָּה יוֹשֵׁב וּשְׁכִינָה עוֹמֶדֶת, כָּךְ בָּנֶיךָ יוֹשְׁבִין וּשְׁכִינָה עוֹמֶדֶת עַל גַּבָּן, כְּשֶׁיִּשְׂרָאֵל נִכְנָסִים לְבָתֵּי כְנֵסִיּוֹת וּלְבָתֵּי מִדְרָשׁוֹת וְקוֹרִין קְרִיאַת שְׁמַע וְהֵן יוֹשְׁבִים לִכְבוֹדִי וַאֲנִי עַל גַּבָּן, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (תהלים פב, א): אֱלֹהִים נִצָּב בַּעֲדַת אֵל.

It is worth pointing out that even though this became a distinctive character trait for the descendants of Avraham, Yitzchok and Yaacov (The Children of Israel, meaning the title of Israel, who were the inheritors of that blessing which came through the Avot from Adam HaRishon. The sign of that blessing was demonstrated via the dry land appearing in the midst of the waters both at the beginning of the Creation and at the splitting of the Red Sea.), it actually began with Adam HaRishon and his descendants in connection with Rosh HaShanah as pointed out from VaYikra Rabbah 29:1 which says:

> בחדש השביעי באחד לחדש - הדא הוא דכתיב (תהלים קיט): לעולם ה' דברך נצב בשמים. תני, בשם ר' אלעזר: בכ"ה באלול נברא העולם. ואתיא דרב כההיא דתני ר' אלעזר דתנינן: בתקיעתא דרב זה היום תחלת מעשיך זכרון ליום ראשון כי חוק לישראל הוא וגו'. ועל המדינות בו יאמר איזו לחרב ואיזו לשלום איזו לרעב ואיזו לשובע ובריות בו יפקדו להזכירם לחיים ולמות. נמצאת אתה אומר: ביום ר"ה, בשעה ראשונה, עלה במחשבה. בשניה, נתייעץ עם מלאכי השרת. בשלישי, כנס עפרו. ברביעי, גבלו. בחמישי, רקמו בששי, עשאו גולם. בשביעי, נפח בו נשמה. בשמיני, הכניסו לגן. בתשיעי, נצטוה. בעשירי, עבר. באחד עשר, נידון. בשנים עשר, יצא בדימוס. **אמר הקדוש ברוך הוא לאדם: זה סימן לבניך** מה אתה נכנסת לפני בדין ונתתי לך דימיס, אף בניך נכנסין לפני בדין ואני נותן להם דימיס. אימתי בראש השנה, בחדש השביעי באחד לחדש:

It is also worth pointing out that from the Jewish viewpoint, it is not only the males that we follow, meaning Avraham, Yitzchok and Yaacov, but we also follow the acts of their wives (*husband and wife are considered as one*) like is expressed in Bereshit Rabbah 60:5 which says in regard to Rivkah from Bereshit 24:16:

> ותרד העינה ותמלא כדה ותעל כל הנשים יורדות וממלאות מן העין, וזו כיון שראו אותה המים, מיד עלו. **אמר לה הקב"ה: את סימן לבניך**, מה את, כיון שראו אותך המים מיד עלו, אף בניך כיון שהבאר רואה אותן, מיד תהיה עולה. הה"ד (במדבר כא): אז ישיר ישראל את השירה הזאת עלי באר ענו בה:

In that context, if you were trying to find a legal term to describe this category of action and to what degree it is binding, it would seem to fall under the domain of *Dat Yehudit* as is discussed in [Mishnah Ketubot 7:6](https://www.sefaria.org/sheets/8573.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en&p3=Mishnah_Ketubot.7&lang3=bi) which says:

> ואלו יוצאות שלא בכתבה, **העוברת על דת משה ויהודית** .ואיזו היא דת משה, מאכילתו שאינו מעשר , ומשמשתו נדה, ולא קוצה לה חלה, ונודרת ואינה מקימת .**ואיזוהי דת יהודית**, יוצאה וראשה פרוע , וטווה בשוק, ומדברת עם כל אדם.אבא שאול אומר, אף המקללת יולדיו בפניו.רבי טרפון אומר, אף הקולנית.ואיזו היא קולנית, לכשהיא מדברת בתוך ביתה ושכניה שומעין קולה.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with מעשה אבות סימן לבנים.  That means that whatever happened to Yaakov will also happen to his descendants.  The only thing that happened to Yaakov here is he told his kids that future generations would bless *their* kids by their names, which seems not relevant to the question.  If you want to have a connection that I'm not seeing, please be more explicit.

Comment: About דת יהודית, sure it's a Jewish custom to bless kids this way, but I'm not sure what you want to do with that.

Comment: @Heshy We bless that our children should be blessed "like Ephraim and Menashe" were blessed.

Comment: You've brought many sources that say that concepts like מעשה אבות סימן לבנים and דת יהודית exist, but you've brought zero sources that relate these concepts to this bracha.