# Origin of using priestly blessing on Friday night

Tags: blessing, sources-mekorot, children-parenting, birchas-kohanim, leil-shabbat

I know why we use Ephraim and Menashe when blessing the children on Friday nights, (see: [Why Does Hashem Bless Us Like Efraim And Menashe?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4806/2246)) but why do we use Birkat Kohanim? Is there any specific reason the custom became to use this, besides just being a nice generic blessing?

While not necessary, I would appreciate sources discussing early uses of Birkat Kohanim in this way.

Comment: You should know some opinions _oppose_ the use of those verses for this purpose, as it is not their appropriate context. See here http://www.vbm-torah.org/archive/halak60/01bless.doc for details.

Comment: Are you asking about use of this blessing in general by non-kohanim, or specifically using it Friday night?

Comment: @mevaqesh I guess in general. The only/major place Ive seen it used by non kohanim is Friday night.

Answer (score 1):

The Kaf HaChaim (262:17) quotes the Siddur Ya'avetz and a discussion from the Petach HaDevir (262:4) regarding the lofty Minhag of fathers and rabbanim to bless the young innocent children on Leil Shabbat as a means of releasing the Shefa Min HaShamayim on their actions and on others. He makes no mention of a specific Berachah, but perhaps the rationale presented is parallel enough to that of the well known idea that they act as the pipes for bringing Shefa down into the world:

> **רמב"ם הלכות תפילה ונשיאת כפים פרק טו הלכה יא**
>
> ואל תתמה ותאמר ומה תועיל ברכת הדיוט זה, שאין קבול הברכה תלוי בכהנים
>   אלא בהקדוש ברוך הוא
>   שנאמר ושמו את שמי על בני ישראל ואני אברכם, הכהנים עושים מצותן שנצטוו
>   בה והקב"ה ברחמיו מברך את ישראל כחפצו.
>
> **ילקוט יוסף תפילה ב הערות סימן קכח - הלכות נשיאת כפים הערה לה**
>
> בגמרא סוטה (לח א) ופסקוהו הפוסקים להלכה. וכתב רבינו בחיי (פר' נשא ו',
>   כג), ומה שהשליח צבור מקריא ברכת כהנים לכהן מלה במלה, כי כך דוגמתו של
>   כהן למעלה שהוא מתברך ומקבל הברכה מעצם הרחמים העליונים, ומברך לכנסת
>   ישראל. וזהו סוד מה שדרשו חז"ל, כל כהן המברך מתברך, שנאמר ואברכה מברכך.
>   וכן הברכה משתלשלת משליח צבור המתעטף בטלית לבנה לכהן, ומהכהן לישראל.
>   ע"כ. והכלי יקר הרחיב הדברים שם, שהחזן הוא בבחינת סרסור המושך שפע צינור
>   ממקור הברכות העליונות, שיחול על ראש הכהן תחלה, עד כדי שיהיה כלי מלא
>   ברכת ה', ולאחר מכן כשהכהן מברך את ישראל, הרי הוא כמריק מכלי מלא אל כלי
>   ריקן, ואלמלא היה החזן מקריא את הכהן תחלה, לא היה הכהן מתברך, ולא היה
>   לו מה להריק ברכה על ישראל. [וכמו שאמרו בזוה"ק (פר' יתרו) דברכתא דלעילא
>   לא שריא באתר ריקניא]...

See also Kaf HaChaim 128:271

Comment: What does Shefa mean?

Comment: Perhaps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohr

Comment: @MDjava It is certainly what you have linked.